# Search incomplete synonym name

Tags: support, api-v2.2, tags, search

Is there is way to search synonym when user is inputting the name. Something like how things work in SO's tag search page.

[image]

`j2se` is a synonym of `java` tag, but it appears in search when searching for `j2s`.

Comment: No, the API does not provide directly for this. But there are only 3000 synonyms and they change rather slowly. So your app can store a table of all 3000, check for new synonyms using `creation_date`, and use this table to augment the API's `inname` search.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BrockAdams. I think it can work.